# Why doesn't t-latch go to infinite state switching?

Tags: logic-gates, latch

I've tried to build a T-Latch with NOR and AND gates in an emulator, but it causes an infinite loop.

1. Initial state, waiting for clock

[image: Initial state]

2. Simulating clock impulse (the second switch)

[image]

3. After that it goes into infinite loops

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Could you explain if there is a way to implement a T-Latch in emulators?

Comment: `but it causes infinite loop` ... that should say `but it causes oscillation`

Comment: those are not NAND gates

Comment: The two switches have exactly the same function. Can you explain their purpose better? You say that you are simulating a "clock **impulse**" but it looks like a latch enable that is continuously asserted. What did you expect would happen? I think the problem is your circuit, not the simulator.

Comment: I would like to find how I can built T-Latch in the simulator, so the desirable circuit need to have one input and one output(and clock if it is needed), when input receives 0 and than 1 output should toggle from 0 to 1 state. On the following 0 and 1 for input output should toggle from 1 to 0 state. I used this simulator https://logic.ly/demo/samples for the examples, but I also tried a few others and they work pretty the same way

Comment: The behavior you want is not a **latch** but rather a **flip-flop**. You need a master/slave flip-flop with two latches. The circuit you have will never work the way you want on any simulator or in real life.

Comment: could you provide an example circuit template in the answer section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the desirable circuit need to have one input and one output(and clock if it is needed), when input receives 0 and than 1 output should toggle from 0 to 1 state. On the following 0 and 1 for input output should toggle from 1 to 0 state.

The following circuit does precisely what you are asking for.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSaWLW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Clicking on the "simulate this circuit" link, will open this circuit in CircuitLab, where you can click the "run" menu and click the "time domain simulation" option.

Or you can run a "live" simulation in Falstad [here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3EDMAOaA2AnGgLDgrNmAEzYZhjYh6RVU14CmAtOQFBjUhEkhZcDsRXmihdaedp26UwaGkUHg5oofUnye0gUK3zREjhspFkybV1Mr96rj0R4di+6rFqOQwiJNnsyeZZpEa3cQTyUaXxpZGkDxVgB3UNlwfhEUGVSoBJB0lLTkYx5IbNyFD2SyrMTKrVKi7LDo8ybixLDvcw7WpJEKSly+qp6cyH6Ckcpu3MRRnPHnIemHcwWp8cHcvjXKPkqthr9wqmIj7rAMIUOtQ7OLkEPzoUHbp+xCmTehyIszPBOu7J-HSWIGhOBDUHYcGPMExbIwqFRO4zSbZWqzGEooaYjF3Ehw6qaKHgPHEl5cYkwsCZbpaam9O70xbjWosxTFACS4BMIBYvR5iBcMDwVEBJyaoL52LuUslyXJUphN3hMuSxDMUrOAqePMqWrMNU07PhusU6pyaDM+otBrslqyACVeb5bJQmFceBAnuCiNARb6RTE-dkmC7yEJQ7bUYT+ogRJGcnGhgnEEmE7pWFywzywzSoH7RW0zOawydaZpID4DZWvtWq3la+B-p6ywcmxHS6pWAB7UJCHCiQiQIKB2DwDCpPBoIiBsTYISIHtcIIDiJgYe0GDwSATtBTmdWIhBRdAA)